# Can I get back a deleted Gmail account after a long time if I still have access to its recovery email?

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

I have a Gmail account which has been deleted for over a year and not been recovered. Lets call it 'X'.

I also have another Gmail account which is the recovery email for 'X'. I still have access to it. Lets call it 'Y'.

Now, when I try to recover X from the Google account recovery page, it says that it can't find my Gmail account, which is expected because it's been more than 30 days. When I try to create a new email address with the same username as X, it says that the username is taken, which is also expected since Google doesn't recycle deleted usernames.

Now, I don't want to open or access the Gmail account 'X' and only want to access one email in which there is an OTP for a site.

I was wondering if somehow I could get that email on X to Y.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as it's been more than 30 days. Even if you somehow recover it, you may not be able to recover the account data.

From [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en):

> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you may be able to get it back. If it’s been awhile since you deleted your account, you may not be able to recover the data in your account.